# Which Miniconda version should I use with Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: python, pi-3

Hi I am trying to install Miniconda2 4.0.5-Linux-x86.sh on my Raspberry Pi 3. Everything starts fine till it installs:setuptools-20.3-py27_0, line 288 binary cannot be excecuted.

Is there already any version of Miniconda which I can run on the Pi3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to have downloaded the wrong package (as indicated by the x86 in the file name). You appear to be trying to install the generic Linux installer. You need the arm version designed for the Pi 3's architecture.

This is the version needed for the Pi3:

[Miniconda3 Linux armv7l (Python 3)](http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh)

Comment: yes I realized it myself. i can confirm the Miniconda2 (Python 2.7) version works fine.